# Why does Finset not have a natural numbers object?

Tags: category-theory, set-theory, topos-theory

Let $C$ be an elementary topos with final object $1$. A natural numbers object is an object $\mathbb{N}$ equipped with morphisms $q:1\longrightarrow \mathbb{N}$ and $s:\mathbb{N}\longrightarrow\mathbb{N}$ such that for any object $A$ and morphisms $z:A\longrightarrow A$ and $f:A\longrightarrow A$ there exists an unique morphism $\phi:\mathbb{N}\longrightarrow A$ such that the obvious diagram is commutative.

For proving that the category Finset doesn't have a NNO I was thinking to use an especific object $A=\{a_{0},...,a_{n}\}$ and morphisms $q:1\longrightarrow A$ such that $q(0):=a_{0}$ and $f:A\longrightarrow A$ such that $f(a_{i})=a_{i+1}$ for all $0\leq i\leq n-1$ and $f(a_{n})= a_{0}$. Then there exists the object $\mathbb{N}$ with $|\mathbb{N}|=m$ with the morphisms $s$ and $z$.

Then I was thinking that we will conclude that $\mathbb{N}\cong \mathbb{Z}_{n}$, because we will have $\phi(z(0)))=a_{0}$, $\phi(s(z(0)))=f(a_{0})=a_{1}$ and $\phi(s^{n}(z(0)))=a_{n}$, but from here I don't know how to get a contradiction.

Thank you very much.

Comment: It is good to see Erdös getting interested in category theory!

Comment: You're right! ^.^

Answer (score 8):

In a topos, $\mathbb{N} \simeq 1 \coprod \mathbb{N}$.

Now suppose we have a finite set $S$ with cardinality $n$. Then $1 \coprod S$ has cardinality $n + 1$, hence is not isomorphic to $S$.

Therefore, there is no natural numbers object in the category of finite sets.

Answer (score 4):

Keep in mind that the morphism $\phi$ you get does not have to be injective. Suppose $\mathbb N$ is a natural numbers object in FinSet, and let $A_n:=\{a_0,\dots,a_n\}$ be the finite set you called $A$. Your choice of $q_n:1\to A_n$ and $f_n:A_n\to A_n$ give rise to a morphism $\phi_n:\mathbb N\to A_n$. So far this is just recapping what you had said.

Now, $\phi_n$ is a priori just some map of sets. It is not necessarily a bijection, so we can not conclude that $|\mathbb N|=|A_n|=n+1$ and similarly cannot conclude that $\mathbb N\cong\mathbb Z_{n+1}$ (note I have $(n+1)$'s where you wrote $n$ since we started indexing the $a_i$'s at $0$ instead of $1$). For example, if $n=1$, it is a priori possible that $\mathbb N=\{0,1,2,3\}$ with $\phi(n)=a_{(n\mod2)}\in A_2$.

So we do not get a contradiction from considering one $A_n$, but we will get one from considering all $A_n$'s. The point is that the $\phi_n$ you constructed is always surjectivie, so we do know that $|\mathbb N|\ge|A_n|=n+1$. In fact, we know this for all values of $n$. Thus, $\mathbb N$ cannot be a finite set, and this is the contradiction.

Comment: But $\phi$ is surjective only if $f:A_{n}\longrightarrow A_{n}$ is of the form as i described, right? Because, if $f=id_{A}$, then $\phi$ may be the constant function $a_{0}$

Comment: Exactly right. There are other choices of $f$ that could have worked (e.g. $f(a_i)=a_{(i+k)\mod(n+1)}$ for fixed $k$ with $\gcd(k,n+1)=1$), but not all choices of $f$ would have worked as your $f=\operatorname{id}_A$ example shows.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution basically works aside from the last paragraph. As [Niven pointed out](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4226661/90543) in their answer the trick to make this work is to consider a family of sets like the one you constructed and show that this forces the cardinality of the hypothetical natural numbers object to be infinite.

**Alternatively**, and this is the main reason I'm writing this answer, you could follow the route suggested by [Mark Saving](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4226701/90543) and prove that in general $\mathbb{N}\cong 1 \amalg \mathbb{N}\newcommand\NN{\mathbb{N}}$, which would immediately give a contradiction.

*Proof:*

Note on terminology. I'm going to call triples $(A,z:1\to A, s:A\to A)$ counting systems. I don't know that this is standard terminology, but I need a name for these things, and this is what I settled on.

Suppose $(\NN,z:1\to \NN, s:\NN\to\NN)$ is a natural numbers object. To show $\NN\cong 1\amalg \NN$,
it suffices to show that $1\amalg \mathbb{N}$ is also a natural numbers object. We define $z' : 1\to 1\amalg \NN$ to be the inclusion $\iota_1$ in the coproduct. We define $s' : 1\amalg \NN\to 1\amalg \NN$ to be $\iota_\NN\circ z + \iota_\NN \circ s$.

Now if $(A,z_A, s_A)$ is another counting system, suppose $f'=f_0+f : 1\amalg \NN\to A$ is a map compatible with the counting systems, i.e., $f'\circ z' = z_A$, $f'\circ s' = s_A\circ f'$. The first equality says $f_0 = z_A$, so $f_0$ is uniquely determined by these equations, and the second equality says that
$$f'(\iota_\NN z+\iota_\NN s) = fz + fs = s_A f' = s_Af_0 + s_Af.$$
This gives us that
$fz=s_Af_0=s_Az_A$ and $fs=s_Af$.
So $f$ is a map of counting systems from $(\NN,z,s)$ to $(A,s_Az_A,s_A)$, and is therefore unique.

Therefore $f'$, if it exists, is unique. On the other hand, we can also use these equations to construct $f_0$ and $f$ to produce a valid map $f'$.